Github Action Runner Not Connecting To Sqlite Database
All the questions on this topic are so advanced, hard to believe that I'm the only dumb person struggling with this. I have a Github Laravel action runner configured with the following yml file:
name: Laravel CI - [a31909e0-4df5-44a1-b595-86f8b53d82ac]

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Print current directory
      run: pwd
    - name: List files in current directory
      run: ls -la
    - name: Check if .env.test exists
      run: test -f ./.env.test && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exist"
    - name: Copy .env and config.php
      run: |
        chmod 777 .env.test
        chmod 777 config.inc.sample.php
        cp ./.env.test ./.env
        cp ./config.inc.sample.php ./config.inc.php
    - name: Create cache directories
      run: |
        mkdir -p storage/framework
        mkdir -p storage/framework/cache
        mkdir -p storage/framework/sessions
        mkdir -p storage/framework/views
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress -- 
      prefer-dist
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database-ci
        touch database-ci/database.sqlite
    - name: Migrate
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database-ci/database.sqlite
      run: php artisan migrate
    - name: Create Livewire Test Directory
      run: mkdir -p tests/Livewire
    - name: Sleep for 10 seconds
      run: sleep 10
    - name: Execute tests via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database-ci/database.sqlite
      run: php artisan test

The issue I'm having is that, while the migrations run successfully in the Migration command using the SQLite connection, the tests fail with the following error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure 
in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 
database-ci/database.sqlite and table_name = some_table and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Here are the env variables configured in the phpunit XML file:
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <env name="PULSE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>

Tried to change the DB_DATABASE value to database-ci/database.sqlite but that didn't make any difference. Tbh I don't think that the test runner is connecting to that SQLite database correctly, I think it's trying to connect to it as a MySQL server.
Thanks.

Did you try setting the absolute path for DB_DATABASE as suggested in this SO thread?

I can give it a try, but I don't think that's the problem. the Migrate command of the same workflow uses the same path and it works. Also, my error comes from the mysql client, the suggested thread's error comes from the sqlite connector, different issue.

All right. That makes sense. What about databases.php? Did you try updating it like the accepted answer on that same SO thread?

In case it helps: "information_schema.tables" in the error message is a very strong hint that Laravel uses a database connection to MySQL/MariaDB or at least generates the SQL that way. If the phpunit.xml file is in use, there should be no need to configure those parameters in the environment of the Microsoft GitHub Shell Action. You have not shared the contents of the .env file. Laravel uses getenv() and the vulcan/php-dot-env package IIRC, use it with scrutiny and double-check your understanding what that package does by reviewing the code and the contents of .env.
